# How to remove html comment from source?

Tags: php

Is any easy method to remove all html comment like `<!-- wp_head()-->` from source from every pages and posts? Maybe using functions.php?
Is any easy method without plugin?

Comment: I think Autoptimize does this, can you look up how they did it?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick way to remove all comments using output buffering and [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). We hook in before WordPress starts outputting the HTML to start the buffer. Then we hook in after WordPress stops outputting the HTML to get the buffer and strip the HTML comment tags from the content.

This code would ideally be in it's own plugin. But it could be in your functions.php if you're really adverse to adding more plugins.

```
namespace StackExchange\WordPress;

//* Start output buffering
function startOutputBuffer() {
  ob_start();
}

//* Print the output buffer
function stopOutputBuffer() {
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  echo strip_html_comments( $html );
}

//* See note for attribution of this code
function strip_html_comments( string $html ) : string {
  return preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/Uis', '', $html);
}

//* Add action before WordPress starts outputting content to start buffer
add_action( 'wp', __NAMESPACE__ . '\startOutputBuffer' );

//* Add action after WordPress stops outputting content to stop buffer
add_action( 'shutdown', __NAMESPACE__ . '\stopOutputBuffer' );
```

Note: Regex from this StackOverflow answer by [Benoit Villière](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235781/6077935).

Comment: coming here late but +1 for giving proper credit, really classy ! cheers

Answer (score 2):

The following WordPress actions are able to filter your code from all HTML comments. Place the PHP code into your `functions.php` file inside the WordPress theme directory.

```
function callback($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('/<!--(.|s)*?-->/', '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
function buffer_start() {
    ob_start("callback");
}
function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
add_action('get_header', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Comment: Works in 2023. Seems like a cleaner option that the previous 2018 option.