# How to remove all comments from JS, HTML, CSS files?

Tags: code

**How to remove all comments from JS, HTML, CSS files?**

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/356159/75371) to remove comments from HTML, but is there a straightfoward way to do it also from all included JS and CSS files?

Comment: You could use node and install modules to clean and compress the JS and CSS. Is there a specific reason you want them removed? If its just for rendering you can modify your Apache to compress html/js/css files and that will remove the comments for you as well.

Comment: the Apache approach is interesting. how would you approach it with note on WordPress since non is not bad on npm modules / deployment pipeline? the reason is that comments are for infernal use, maybe some code is commented because it's not ready for production... (continuous deployment, hiding features which are temporarily disabled for example)

Comment: For your setup I would do Node/NPM since you can do that in the pipeline and have it do all of the cleaning and compression there. If you go for the Apache approach you can look at an article like https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/how-enable-gzip-compression-apache.html to help you along, its simple and works quite well.